# Promise doesn't wait for functions promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I've been working on a scraper project.

Now I've implemented many things but I've been stuck on this one thing.

So first let me explain workflow: Scrapers are called in `scraping-service` module, where I wait for the promise of the functions called to be resolved. Data is fetched in scrapers, and passed to the `data_functions` object where data is: merged, validated and inserted into DB.

Now here is the code:

`scraping-service`

```
const olxScraper = require('./scrapers/olx-scraper');
const santScraper = require('./scrapers/sant-scraper');
//Calling scraper from where we want to get data about apartments
const data_functions = require('./data-functions/dataF');

let count = 1;

Promise.all([
  olxScraper.olxScraper(count),
  santScraper.santScraper(count),
]).then(() => data_functions.validateData(data_functions.mergedApartments));
```

So here I'm waiting for the promise of these two functions, and then passing merged data to `validateData` method in the `data_functions`.

Here is the scraper:

```
const axios = require('axios'); //npm package - promise based http client
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); //npm package - used for web-scraping in server-side implementations
const data_functions = require('../data-functions/dataF');

//olxScraper function which as paramater needs count which is sent in the scraping-service file.
exports.olxScraper = async (count) => {
  const url = `https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?vrsta=samoprodaja&kategorija=23&sort_order=desc&kanton=9&sacijenom=sacijenom&stranica=${count}`;
  //url where data is located at.
  const olxScrapedData = [];
  try {
    await load_url(url, olxScrapedData); //pasing the url and empty array
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Function that does loading URL part of the scraper, and starting of process for fetching raw data.
const load_url = async (url, olxScrapedData) => {
  await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    fetch_raw_html($).each((index, element) => {
      process_single_article($, index, element, olxScrapedData);
    });

    process_fetching_squaremeters(olxScrapedData); // if i place 
 //data_functions.mergeData(olxScrapedData); here it will work
  });
};

//Part where raw html data is fetched but in div that we want.
const fetch_raw_html = ($) => {
  return $('div[id="rezultatipretrage"] > div')
    .not('div[class="listitem artikal obicniArtikal  i index"]')
    .not('div[class="obicniArtikal"]');
};

//Here is all logic for getting data that we want, from the raw html.
const process_single_article = ($, index, element, olxScrapedData) => {
  $('span[class="prekrizenacijena"]').remove();
  const getLink = $(element).find('div[class="naslov"] > a').attr('href');
  const getDescription = $(element).find('div[class="naslov"] > a > p').text();
  const getPrice = $(element)
    .find('div[class="datum"] > span')
    .text()
    .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
    .replace(' ', '');
  const getPicture = $(element).find('div[class="slika"] > img').attr('src');
  //making array of objects with data that is scraped.
  olxScrapedData[index] = {
    id: getLink.substring(27, 35),
    link: getLink,
    description: getDescription,
    price: parseFloat(getPrice),
    picture: getPicture,
  };
};

//Square meters are needed to be fetched for every single article.
//This function loads up all links in the olxScrapedData array, and updating objects with square meters value for each apartment.
const process_fetching_squaremeters = (olxScrapedData) => {
  const fetchSquaremeters = Promise.all(
    olxScrapedData.map((item) => {
      return axios.get(item.link).then((response) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        const getSquaremeters = $('div[class="df2  "]')
          .first()
          .text()
          .replace('m2', '')
          .replace(',', '.')
          .split('-')[0];
        item.squaremeters = Math.round(getSquaremeters);
        item.pricepersquaremeter = Math.round(
          parseFloat(item.price) / parseFloat(getSquaremeters)
        );
      });
    })
  );

  fetchSquaremeters.then(() => {
    data_functions.mergeData(olxScrapedData); //Sending final array to mergeData function.
    return olxScrapedData;
  });
};
```

Now if I `console.log(olxScrapedData)` in the `fetchSquaremeters.then` it will output scraped apartments, but it doesn't want to call the function `data_functions.mergeData(olxScrapedData)`. But if I add that block in the `load_url`, it will trigger the functions and data is being merged, but without square meters things, and I really need that data.

So my question is, how to make this work? Do I need to call function somewhere else or?

What I want is just that this last `olxScrapedData` be sent to this function `mergeData` so that my arrays from different scrapers would be merged into one.

Thanks!

Edit: also here is the other scrapers how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/oh03mp8t/. Note that in this scraper there is no any promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this: `const process_fetching_squaremeters = async (olxScrapedData) ...`
and then `await fetchSquaremeters.then(..)`.

James, in answer before told you what is happening. You must wait for this promise to be resolved, in order to all be executed correctly. If you don't have experience with async/await, promises, I suggest you watch some courses on them, to really understand what is happening here

Comment: Actually in this case, you can replace the `await` keyword with a `return` statement, which will return the promise, which will eventually be caught by `await load_url()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing return/await statements from inside your promise/async statements, especially when your last statement is also a promise?

Without that, you may be simply asking the promise to be executed at a later time, rather than returning the result and making $.all() wait for it.

Comment: I'm fairly new to the async/promises, so I'm learning this new stuff right now. So, I'm missing async somewhere in the code? Are you thinking on the code of the scraper or somewhere else?

Comment: In some ways, I think the old Promise syntax is actually easier to understand, especially if you are new to promises (the Bluebird library made things nice). Async/await syntax is doing the exact same thing under the hood but is syntactic sugar to make it read like synchronous code. I would recommend writing out some unit-tests or sandbox code using both sets of syntax, and use console.log() statements to understand the ordering of events in different edge cases.

Comment: Javascript is a single-threaded language. What an async promise means, is to add the function to the end of the call-stack (event loop) and run it once the current function has finished or interrupted. Calling an async function returns a promise object. Promises are chainable. If you are calling async functions in the middle of async functions, then get in the habit of explicitly returning your promises. This means you can call await at the top of the chain and it will wait for all the nested callbacks to complete.